# Using Mypy local stubs

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying the typing hint introduced by Python 3.5 and got a problem by using local stubs as the typing hint with mypy.

The experiment I do is to create kk.py containing

```
def type_check(a):
    pass
```

Also, I put kk.pyi containing

```
def type_check(a: int):...
```

in the same directory. In this way, I tried to trigger the error of *"incompatible types in assignment"* by passing a string to `type_check` in `kk.py`. However, when I ran `mypy kk.py`, I get no error.

Thus I tried another way that mypy doc suggests, which is to set environment variable MYPYPATH to `~/some/path/stub` and put `kk.pyi` in the directory. I didn't get any error again.

Anyone can help me on this?

Here is the mypy wiki on [how](https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Creating-Stubs-For-Python-Modules) to use a local stub.

Comment: Found the cause and solution here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5520#issuecomment-426371485

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do not know why someone have voted down this question without answering it or commenting about why he/she disliked it, but here is the answer I figured out:

The stub file of mypy only works when importing a module. Thus, if you have

```
def try_check(a):
    pass
```

in kk.py, and

```
def try_check(a: int):...
```

in kk.pyi in the same directory with kk.py or in the directory that the MYPYPATH specifies, mypy will type check the python file if you import kk.
It is, if you have

```
import .kk
kk.try_check('str')
```

in test.py and run *mypy test.py*, mypy will report the type conflict. However, it will not report the conflict if you have

```
try_check('str')
```

in kk.py.

You can type check functions in the program that contains the function definition If you write the typing hint explicitly in the definition of the function. For instance, you can write

```
def try_check(a: int):
    pass

try_check('str')
```

in kk.py and then mypy *kk.py*. Mypy will report the type conflict.

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with this exact issue. I really don't understand why mypy works like this. Any ideas?

Comment: @SolomonBothwell I feel the initial attempt to have this static check program for big modulo like Django, so it supposes the user will check things in a package rather than self-written programs.

Comment: You can absolutely type-check your own programs, there's just no need or reason to use separate stub files. If your program imports a third-party library that has no annotations, but you want to use them, that's when you need local stubs.

Comment: @OJFord sure, as the documentation demonstrates, we can do it. However, the point of this post is HOW can do it with a separate stub file rather an WHY we want to do it.

Comment: @OJFord also I'd prefer using local stubs instead of in-place typehinting, as the syntax is quite bloated in its current state and kinda makes the code unpleasant to read. Not to mention the circular imports and the workarounds you need to apply for the case of more complex typehints.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer mentioned, **unfortunately** Mypy doesn't use the `X.pyi` stub file against `X.py` itself when you run `mypy X.py`.

This issue is addressed here as well:
https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5028

The only solution I found to check the module itself is using [`mypy.stubtest`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubtest.html#automatic-stub-testing-stubtest):

> A common problem with stub files is that they tend to diverge from the
> actual implementation. Mypy includes the stubtest tool that can
> automatically check for discrepancies between the stubs and the
> implementation at runtime.

The usage is simple, Just run `python -m mypy.stubtest X` (X is the name of the module without `.py` extension)

Example:

```
$ python3 -m pip install mypy

$ cat library.py
x = "hello, stubtest"

def foo(x=None):
    print(x)

$ cat library.pyi
x: int

def foo(x: int) -> None: ...

$ python3 -m mypy.stubtest library
error: library.foo is inconsistent, runtime argument "x" has a default value but stub argument does not
Stub: at line 3
def (x: builtins.int)
Runtime: at line 3 in file ~/library.py
def (x=None)

error: library.x variable differs from runtime type Literal['hello, stubtest']
Stub: at line 1
builtins.int
Runtime:
hello, stubtest
```