# Using Mypy stub file doesn't work as same as writing type hint in the definition of function

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I try writing the type hint explicitly in the definition of the function

```
# test.py
def annotated(x: int, y: str) -> bool:
    return x < y
```

ran `python3.5 -m mypy test.py` and got following message

```
test.py:2: error: Unsupported operand types for > ("str" and "int")
```

It's correct. But when I try using stub file

```
# test.py
def annotated(x, y):
    return x < y

# test.pyi
def annotated(x: int, y: str) -> bool: ...
```

I got nothing. I saw this answer [Using Mypy local stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537194/using-mypy-local-stubs). So I try to `import`.

```
from test import annotated

annotated(2, 3)
```

It's ok. I got

```
error: Argument 2 to "annotated" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

But call `annotated(2, 's')` still got nothing.
So What should I do to check illegal operation with a stub file? Thanks

Comment: You might want to try asking [mypy gitter channel](https://gitter.im/python/mypy) this question -- I suspect this behavior might be by design, but don't remember for certain, and it'll likely be quicker to just ask the core devs directly.

Comment: As I understand, stub files only provide a "type API" of a module for other modules that use it. In other words bodies of function implementations are not checked against stub files. If you want to change this, then you can open an issue on mypy tracker: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues

Comment: Found the cause and solution here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5520#issuecomment-426371485